# I'm looking for an efficient way to merge multiple empty column in mysql to a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

[Result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LogT.jpg)

I need an effective way to merge up each row to a single column.

Here's my sql statement.

```
 SELECT students.MatricNo,
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE101',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE102',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE103',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE104',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE103',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 128' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE128',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GCE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'GCE101',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 105' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE105',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE107',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 108' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE108',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 109' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE109', 
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE102',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GES 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'GES107',
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'SPE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'SPE104'


FROM results
INNER JOIN students ON results.Student = students.Guid
INNER JOIN courses ON results.Course = courses.Guid
INNER JOIN departments ON students.Department = departments.Guid

WHERE departments.Code = 'KHE' AND results.Level = 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pivot your data. 
 This is done by using GROUP BY and MAX functions.

**Query**

```
    SELECT 
        unpivotted.MatricNo
      , MAX(unpivotted.KHE101) AS KHE101
      ...
      ...
      , MAX(unpivotted.SPE104) AS SPE104
    FROM (

     SELECT students.MatricNo,
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE101',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE102',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE103',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE104',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE103',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 128' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE128',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GCE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'GCE101',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 105' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE105',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE107',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 108' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE108',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 109' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'KHE109', 
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'TEE102',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GES 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'GES107',
    (CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'SPE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END) AS 'SPE104'


    FROM results
    INNER JOIN students ON results.Student = students.Guid
    INNER JOIN courses ON results.Course = courses.Guid
    INNER JOIN departments ON students.Department = departments.Guid

    WHERE departments.Code = 'KHE' AND results.Level = 100

    ) AS unpivotted

GROUP BY 
  unpivotted.MatricNo
ORDER BY
  unpivotted.MatricNo ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Raymond, this is construct, it showed it just the way i expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever have one result, you could concatenate the data:

```
 SELECT students.MatricNo,
concat((CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 103' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 128' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GCE 101' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 105' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 108' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'KHE 109' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END), 
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'TEE 102' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'GES 107' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END),
(CASE WHEN courses.Code = 'SPE 104' THEN results.Total ELSE '' END)) as [NewColumn]


FROM results
INNER JOIN students ON results.Student = students.Guid
INNER JOIN courses ON results.Course = courses.Guid
INNER JOIN departments ON students.Department = departments.Guid

WHERE departments.Code = 'KHE' AND results.Level = 100
```

Comment: Wrong... MySQL does not support string concatenation with the + sign .. SQL-Server does support string concatenation with the + sign... MySQL supports string concatenation with the function `CONCAT()` or with pipes `||` if you use `SET SESSION sql_mode = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT')` first.

Comment: Edited accordingly. Thank you